# Magento2.4.6: How to remove duplicatation of code in this scenario?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have a module in which there are 2 custom grids and these two grids have the same crud functionality but different classes, but the inner logic is the same, how can I achieve this in a more optimized way?

**Note: Both grids have their own table and model classes**

[image]

is there a way I can perform crud functionality on these grids without creating separate classes for each crud operation?

This is the delete operation class, which is almost same in both scenario

```
// check if we know what should be deleted
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $model = $this->modelFactory->create();
    $resourceModel = $this->resourceModelFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($id) {
        try {
            // init modelFactory and delete
            $country = $resourceModel->load($model, $id);
            $country->delete($model);
            // display success message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('The item has been deleted.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // display error message
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            // go back to edit form
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
        }
    }
    // display error message
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('We can\'t find a item to delete.'));
    // go to grid
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```

if there any question let me know?